# Open all workbooks in folder with date as folder name

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently trying to open up every workbook in a given folder in which the folder is named as the date (ex: 6-15-2020 and the next day the folder will be named 6-16-2020). The files within this folder will differ in name each day as well

```
  Sub Pull_Trade_Data()

Dim TradeFolder As String
Dim tradeFile As String

TradeFolder = "Z:\1. Investing Operations\Trades"

tradeFile = Dir(TradeFolder & "Today_" & Format(Date, "MM-DD-YYY") & "\*.csv")


Do While tradeFile <> ""

Workbooks.Open Filename:=TradeFolder & "\" & tradeFile

tradeFile = Dir

Loop


End Sub
```

The problem I've been facing is I don't think the date is properly formatted. I've tried the same macro but instead of the

```
`TradeFolder = "Z:\1. Investing Operations\Trades"

tradeFile = Dir(TradeFolder & "Today_" & Format(Date, "MM-DD-YYY") & "\*.csv")
```

I used

```
TradeFolder = "Z:\1. Investing Operations\Trades\6-12-2020"
tradeFile = Dir(TradeFolder & "\*.csv")
```

and this seemed to work which leads me to believe that's where the problem lays.
Thanks!

Comment: You can always check with `Debug.Print`... You'd probably see that you'd need `Format(Date, "m-d-yyyy")` to prevent `06...` since that's not how your folder is named.

Comment: You are using `Today_` in the code that does not work, but not in the code that is working. Your description and the the code that you say works, implies that `Today_` is not actually part of any folder's name.

Comment: Iin your code you have "Today_" in the foldername, whereas in you trial it is just the date. What is correct?